# Path returns at negative number string - UmbracoHelper

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I have upgraded an Umbraco 7 CMS to Umbraco 13.

As part of my custom search endpoint I need to return a path, but the path property returns only a negative number as a string. eg. -1,1440,5787. This is everywhere i use Ubraco Helper. In the Umbraco UI i can see the correct path.

Here is my code for one of the locations, i can work around it everywhere else.

```c#
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> basisSideContentNodes = _umbracoHelper.ContentAtRoot().SelectMany(root => root.DescendantsOrSelfOfType("BasisSide"));

basisSideNodes = basisSideContentNodes
    .Where(node => node.Name.ToLower().Contains(query.SearchTerm.ToLower()) ||
    node.Value<string>("tekst").ToLower().Contains(query.SearchTerm.ToLower()))
    .Select(node => new SearchResult
    {
        Id = node.Id,
        Name = node.Name,
        Content = node.Value<string>("tekst"),
        Path = $"/{node.Path}"
    }).ToList();
```

Please help me. Is there a way to get the path on the backend?

I expected it to return a string with the path to the node.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a URL method on IPublishedContent.
[IPublishedContent Documentation](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/querying/ipublishedcontent/properties#url-publishedurlprovider-culture-null-urlmode-mode-urlmode.default-extension-method)

```c#
    basisSideNodes = basisSideContentNodes
    .Where(node => node.Name.ToLower().Contains(query.SearchTerm.ToLower()) ||
    node.Value<string>("tekst").ToLower().Contains(query.SearchTerm.ToLower()))
    .Select(node => new SearchResult
    {
        Id = node.Id,
        Name = node.Name,
        Content = node.Value<string>("tekst"),
        Path = node.Url()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what's going on here:

The value of the Path property on an Umbraco Content node is actually a comma-delimited list of the path hierarchy for that particular content node.

All content starts at the Content root (-1), and is in a tree hierarchy, so you can use the path to determine the position in the tree of a particular node identified by the content Ids of each ancestor.

Similarly, nodes in the Media tree structure have the same property, starting with -1 representing the Media root node.

As you have discovered, to retrieve the Url for a content node, you need to use the `Url()` extension method - under the hood, Umbraco is going through a series of "Content Finders" to determine the url for a specific node based on the request (for example, to determine the domain) and the position of the node in the tree.

It's also worth exploring the parameters to the `Url()` extension - some of this includes the ability to return a fully qualified Url (by default you will get a root-relative url - e.g. /tekst/).